# map is shown incorrectly after toggling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui-map api. Initially, I want to hide my map. So I changed 'display' property to 'none'. However, when I show it by jquery's show() function, only quarter part of map is appearing correctly. On the other hand, If I don't set display property to none, there is not any problem. Here is a screenshot and my code related part of that problem:

[image: Above part is initial view, below part is after calling show()]

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="display : none; width : 100%; height : 300px;"></div>

$("#map_toggle").click( function() 
    {
        if ($("#map_toggle").text() == "Find Address >>>")
            $("#map_toggle").text("Collapse <<<");
        else
            $("#map_toggle").text("Find Address >>>");

        $('#map_canvas').slideToggle("slow");

    });
```

By the way, map_canvas div is inside of a table.

Comment: If the `display:none` isn't present does it display correctly?  If so try doing a `.hide()` on the map once the DOM is loaded. so `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#map_canvas').hide(); );`

Comment: rough guess.. you can try setting the z-index to some negative value instead of setting display to none. Another thing you can try is setting opacity to 0 initially and setting it to 1 when you need it displayed..

Comment: Yes .hide() make sense. However, here is a new problem. Actually, this page is called by $.post() method. Problem is when this page is called second time. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @techfoobar, none of them you suggested solve the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, I am using Chrome, when I click 'Inspect Element', map is shown correctly. So what does Inspect Element do?